# How to pass activity name into to a function and define function in another file

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hi I am developing a android application using Kotlin, when one activity starts I like to put progress bar. For example when user click sign up button in the login page the progress bar will show in the login page, so for that I use AsyncTask. I define the function in anther file and call it it login page. It works well. But I like to put the same thing in other pages also, like when click forget password from login or click login from signup or whatever, so I think passing activity name will be make it easier.

Here my code.

```
class Loading : AppCompatActivity() {



    companion object {
        class MyTask(private val logInActivity: LogInActivity) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            //TODO: Have to fix the error, when back to login the loading is showing
            override fun doInBackground(vararg unUsed: Void?): Void? {
                return null
            }
            override fun onPreExecute() {
                logInActivity.progressDialog.show()
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
                var intent = Intent(logInActivity, SignUp::class.java)
                logInActivity.startActivity(intent)

                super.onPostExecute(result)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this code, it's just setting the progress bar to the login activity only, how to password and activity name into the function and rather statically define loginActivity how can I replace it with passed activity names.

like,

```
<activityName>.progressDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate class or method to take context and message... then show a progress view... I have done it like this in one of my project...

```
class ProgressService(private val mContext: Context) {
    private var mProgressDialog: Dialog? = null
    override fun showProgressBar(message: String?) {

        hideProgressBar()
        mProgressDialog = Dialog(mContext, R.style.ProgressViewTheme)
        val view: View =
            (mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater)
                .inflate(R.layout.progress_indicator, null)
        val progressView: AVLoadingIndicatorView = view.findViewById(R.id.progressView)
        val progressMessageTv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.progressMessageTv)

        progressMessageTv.text = message
        progressView.show()

        mProgressDialog?.setContentView(view)
        mProgressDialog?.setCancelable(false)

        try {
            mProgressDialog?.show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun hideProgressBar() {
        try {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog?.dismiss()
                mProgressDialog = null
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog!!.isShowing) {
            mProgressDialog!!.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for progress_indicator. I used a third party library to show fancy loading animation....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#88000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_white_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/progressView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:indicatorName="LineScalePulseOutRapidIndicator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressMessageTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            tools:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then from where you want to call it...

```
val progressIndicator = ProgressService(this)
progressIndicator.showProgressBar("Please wait...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a abstract BaseActivity and extend in all your Activities.

Like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected Context context;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = BaseActivity.this;
    }

    protected void showProgressDialog()
    {
        if (alertDialog == null)
        {
            alertDialog = new CustomDialog(context);
        }
        if (!alertDialog.isShowing())
        {
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    protected void hideProgressDialog()
    {
        if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing())
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected void showToast(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

use showProgressDialog() and hideProgressDialog() to show and hide dialog.

this approach is much easy to use.